# how to find sqlite query returns no row +Android

Tags: android, sqlite

i'm getting following error in android..

```
 04-23 12:55:51.452: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(486): Caused by:          android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
```

.. Due to it returns zero matching row for the query and activity closes. how can i fix the problem in code? TIA

Comment: Can you give an example of your query code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

count() method for getting number of rows return by the executed query.

Eg: `Cursor c =
                db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    "_id", "code", "name"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            int numRows = c.count();`

in the above code the query execution returns a cursor object and using that object you can get the number of rows returned. Hope it helps...

Comment: It is even possible that the returned cursor is null, so it is necessary to check before invoking getCount(). Never found in the documentation the list of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use code something like this:

```
cursor.getString(0);
```

but it is better to do it in that way:

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_column_name_));
```